git tag : fatalFailed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref from jenkins
i'm trying to tag my projet in gitlat repo within jenkins :
           stage ("Deploy"){
              if ( fast_fe != '--tag--'){ 
          withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'jenkinsgitlab', , gitToolName: 'git-tool')]) {
            sh "git tag -a ${fast_fe} -m 'test'"
        }}

but i'm geting this error :
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 1.8.3.1'
 Masking supported pattern matches of $GIT_PASSWORD or $GIT_ASKPASS
 [Pipeline] {
 [Pipeline] sh
 + git tag -a 1.17 -m test
 fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.

could you help please to get ride of this error please ?
